# Exec Format Error Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I have a basic C++ program in Eclipse CDT:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

However, when I try to build it, I get an Exec Format Error. Here is the output produced by the compiler

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o hey.o "..\\hey.cpp" 
g++: error: spawn: Exec format error
```

I am using MinGW Toolchain. I am on 64-bit Windows, and I think that may have something to do with it. Would anyone know how to get this program running?

**Edit**
Running the exact command in command prompt in the directory where my source file is works just fine, without throwing errors, but it still doesn't work in Eclipse

Comment: The "-c" option tells the compiler to produce an object file.  The "-o" specifies the name of the object file.  I don't see any statements to create an executable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Would you know why Eclipse is giving me this error, then? When I copy-paste the command into command prompt, it works just fine, giving me an object file. It's when I try and build it through Eclipse that gives this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have fixed this myself by installing the 64-bit version of MinGW (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/). It now compiles and builds noramlly